# Определить стили

Tags: css

Помогите определить стили для `Teacher`, не меняя HTML.

```css
{
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ul class="one">
  <li class="two">
    <a class="three">
      <span class="four">Student</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="two">
    <a class="three">
      <span class="four">Teacher</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```css
ul.one>li:nth-child(2) span {
  font-weight: bold;
  animation: 1s ellipse ease-in-out infinite;
  position: absolute;
}

@keyframes ellipse {
  50% {
    transform: scale(2);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="one">
  <li class="two">
    <a class="three">
      <span class="four">Student</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="two">
    <a class="three">
      <span class="four">Teacher</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

как вариант

```css
{
  font-weight: bold;
}

 .one li:nth-child(2) {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="one">
  <li class="two">
    <a class="three">
      <span class="four">Student</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="two">
    <a class="three">
      <span class="four">Teacher</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Любой из перечисленных ниже через запятую, тут может быть очень много вариантов.

```css
li:nth-child(2) .four,
li:nth-child(2) span,
.two:nth-child(2) span,
.two:nth-child(2) .four,
.two:last-child span,
.two:last-child  .four {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ul class="one">
  <li class="two">
    <a class="three">
      <span class="four">Student</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="two">
    <a class="three">
      <span class="four">Teacher</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.two + .two {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ul class="one">
  <li class="two">
    <a class="three">
      <span class="four">Student</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="two">
    <a class="three">
      <span class="four">Teacher</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```